# findOrCreate with include - sequelize.js

Tags: javascript, sequelize.js

I want to create a *Tournament* (if not exists), and a *Match* (if not exists) associated to the Tournament.

```
let [match, created] = await Match.findOrCreate( {
  where: {scoreHome: 97, Tournament: {name: "USA South Men's Basketball"}}, 
  include: [Tournament]
})
```

If the tournament 'USA South Men's Basketball' is already in the db (let's say with id 1), then the match should be created with TournamentId: 1. If there is already a match in the db with `{scoreHome: 97 and TournamentId: 1}`, then no match should be created.

```
  let Match = sequelize.define('Match', {
    scoreHome: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    //...
  })

  Match.associate = models => {
    Match.belongsTo(models.Tournament)
  }
```

**EDIT**
Here is the error:

> [Error: Invalid value [object Object]]

This works fine

```
let match = await Match.create({
    scoreHome: 97, Tournament: {name: "USA South Men's Basketball"}
  },{include: [Tournament]}
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure sequelize will allow this "deep findOrCreate".
But you can achieve the wanted effect using two queries, and the sequelize transaction to make sure the two are linked together:

```
const t = await sequelize.transaction();

try {
  const [tournament] = await Tournament.findOrCreate({
    where: {name: "USA South Men's Basketball"},
    { transaction: t }
  })
  const [match] = await Match.findOrCreate({
    where: {scoreHome: 97, tournamentId: tournament.id},
    { transaction: t }
  })
  t.commit()
} catch(err) {
  t.rollback()
}
```

It is a bit more verbose, but with this you are sure of what you do, and it is also (personal opinion) more readable for another dev reading that after you.