# SequelizeForeignKeyConstraintError on nested findOrCreate inside a loop

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, sequelize.js

I am trying to insert multiple rows on 2 related tables using sequelize with mysql.

Based on [sequelize transaction cannot insert because of foreign key?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45615767/sequelize-transaction-cannot-insert-because-of-foreign-key) I tried to create a transaction and it seems to work if I execute the promise only once, but it fails if I execute the code on a loop showing a foreign key issue.

Here is the code:

```
const config = {
    "username": "root",
    "password": "",
    "database": "sequelize_test",
    "host": "127.0.0.1",
    "dialect": "mysql",
    "pool": {
        "max": 1,
        "min": 0,
        "idle": 20000,
        "acquire": 20000
    }
};

const Sequelize = require('sequelize')
const sequelize = new Sequelize(config.database, config.username, config.password, config)

const Project = sequelize.define('projects', {
    id: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
        allowNull: false,
        autoIncrement: true,
        primaryKey: true
    },
    authorId: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER
    },
    name: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING
    }
})

const Author = sequelize.define('authors', {
    id: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
        allowNull: false,
        autoIncrement: true,
        primaryKey: true
    },
    name: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
    }
})

Author.hasMany(Project, {
    foreignKey: 'authorId',
    sourceKey: 'id'
})
Project.belongsTo(Author, {
    foreignKey: 'id'
})

sequelize
    .sync({
        force: true
    })
    .then(() => {

        var projectAuthors = [{
            projectName: "Proj 1",
            authorName: "Author 1"
        }, {
            projectName: "Proj 2",
            authorName: "Author 1"
        }, {
            projectName: "Proj 3",
            authorName: "Author 1"
        }, {
            projectName: "Proj 4",
            authorName: "Author 2"
        }, {
            projectName: "Proj 5",
            authorName: "Author 3"
        }];

        //Insert all the records on the array
        projectAuthors.forEach(function(project) {

            sequelize
                .transaction(function(t) {
                    //First insert the author
                    return Author.findOrCreate({
                        where: {
                            name: project.authorName
                        },
                        transaction: t

                    }).spread(function(author) {
                        //With the id obtained on the previous step, insert the project
                        return Project.findOrCreate({
                            where: {
                                name: project.projectName,
                                authorId: author.id
                            },
                            transaction: t
                        });
                    })

                });

        });
    });
```

**Edit**

Following the suggestion from  Ellebkey, here is my controller using include.

```
sequelize
.sync({
    force: true
})
.then(() => {

    var projectAuthors = [{
        projectName: "Proj 1",
        authorName: "Author 1"
    }, {
        projectName: "Proj 2",
        authorName: "Author 1"
    }, {
        projectName: "Proj 3",
        authorName: "Author 1"
    }, {
        projectName: "Proj 4",
        authorName: "Author 2"
    }, {
        projectName: "Proj 5",
        authorName: "Author 3"
    }];

    //Insert all the records on the array
    projectAuthors.forEach(function(project) {

        sequelize
            .transaction(function(t) {
                //First insert the author
                return Project.findOrCreate({
                    where: {
                        name: project.projectName,
                        author: {
                            name: project.authorName
                        }
                    },
                    include: [{
                        association: Project.Author,
                    }],
                    transaction: t
                });

            });
    });
});
```

It does fail with:

> Invalid value { name: 'Author 3' }

**Edit 2 (table creation works)**

Thanks to the suggestions from Ellebkey and some playing around, my model looks like this:

```
const Project = sequelize.define('projects', {
    name: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING
    }
});

const Author = sequelize.define('authors', {
    name: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
    }
});

Project.belongsTo(Author, { as: 'Author', foreignKey : 'authorId'});
Author.hasMany(Project, { as: 'Author', foreignKey : 'authorId'});
```

But using the create() code from the answer, I still get this:

> Unhandled rejection Error: Invalid value { name: undefined }

Btw I am using sequelize 4.37.6

Thanks in advance

Comment: You can use `include` on `create` [here](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/tutorial/associations.html#creating-with-associations) is the documentation.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I checked include, but I cannot seem to make it work with findOrCreate(), I get: Invalid value { name: 'Author 3' } The problem seems related to this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45530818/findorcreate-with-include-sequelize-js

Comment: can you please updated your new controller?

Comment: I just updated my question with the new controller

Answer (score 0):

Ok first, for my experience is not recommended use `foreignKey` for the associations, it gets confuse. Use `as` instead, and also you don't need to create the `id` of each model, sequelize do it for you.

```
const Project = sequelize.define('projects', {
    name: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING
    }
})
```

Now, going back to the associations, this will create a `AuthorId` column on your `Project` table

```
Project.belongsTo(Author, { as: 'Author'})

const Author = sequelize.define('authors', {
    name: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
    }
})

Author.hasMany(Project, { as: 'Author'})


sequelize
    .sync({
        force: true
    })
    .then(() => {
```

And last, for your `create` with `include` you have to create your object according how you declared before. Think it as you will do it with a `Find` you get your `Author` with the `Projects` so each object should be like this:

```
        var projectAuthors = [{
            name: "Author 1",
            //This must have the same syntax as you declared on your asociation
            Author: [{
                name: "Proj 1"
            },{
                name: "Proj 2"
            }]
        },{
            name: "Author 2",
            Author: [{
                name: "Proj 3"
            },{
                name: "Proj 4"
            }]
        },];

        projectAuthors.forEach(function(project) {

        sequelize
            .transaction(function(t) {
                //First insert the author
                return Author.findOrCreate({
                    where: {
                        //check this I'm not sure
                        name: project.name, //this is the Author name
                    },
                    include: [{
                        model: Project,
                        as: 'Author'
                    }],
                    transaction: t
                });

            });
        });
    });
```

The error that you was getting was because you never declared `authorName` on your models.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the suggestions of edit on the id and foreign key columns on the model! It makes the entity definition simpler... However, when I change the belongsTo() and hasMany clauses, the example throws the following error: equelizeDatabaseError: Duplicate column name 'authorId' (I deleted the previous tables first) Apparently the query tries to create the same column twice... I will update the question.

Comment: Then just change the `as` name on the `hasMany` association. It will keep the `belongsTo` name.

Comment: Correction, I think I managed to fix the table creation, but the insertion still fails. I will update the question

Comment: Oh I see, I didn't change the variable on the `where` remember we changed the object so `project. projectName` does not exist. Now for duplicated projects I'm not quite sure how to do it.